# Merge remaining part of split array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have framed the following code to split the array into 4 parts and obtain first part separately. Now, I need to obtain the other remaining parts as joined separate array.

```
test = [(0,1,2),(9,0,1),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)]
print(test)
test_np = np.array_split(test,4)
np2 = test_np[2]
```

Then I can merge the other 3 parts into new array `np_new = [(0,1,2),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)]`

I can't figure out how to do it? It should help me even if I choose the 2nd part and look forward to merging 1st,3rd and 4th part.

Comment: Do you need `np.concatenate(test_np[1:])`?

Comment: Please give out a sample for what you want get when you choose the 2nd part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, 'test' is a list of tuples, so you dont need numpy:

```
import numpy as np

test = [(0,1,2),(9,0,1),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)]
t_0 = test[:1]
t_1 = test[1]
new_test= t_0+test[2:]
print(new_test)   
# as np.array:
np_test=np.array(test)
```

If you have a numpy array in the first place:

```
import numpy as np
np_test = np.array([(0,1,2),(9,0,1),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)])
new_np_test = np.vstack((np_test[0], np_test[2:]))
```

Comment: What if I have to loop in for instance;when I select 2nd part,I can merge 1st,3rd and 4th parts ?

Comment: how to do it if test is np.array from start ? @AlexNe

Comment: Edited answer. If thats what youre looking for, pls mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by slicing python arrays. For example, with an array

> x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

you can slice with numerous possibilities. x[1:3] returns 1st through 3rd elements of the array. x[:3] returns zeroth till 3rd element. x[4:] returns fourth till the end of the array.

> x[1:3] = ['b','c'],
>   x[:3] = ['a','b','c'],
>   x[4:] = ['e','f','g','h']

For your example,

```
test = [(0,1,2),(9,0,1),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)]
print(test)
np1 = test[0]
# To keep the rest in test matrix
test = test[1:]
```

Comment: What if I have to loop in for instance;when I select 2nd part,I can merge 1st,3rd and 4th parts ?